# One method policy in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I need some help. My professor give us an assignment that we need to "extract" these codes into ONE METHOD ONLY. Is there a way to do it? It's a heap code sorting algorithm. I'm currently do have a little knowledge about programming so bear with me guys. Can you help me?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class HeapSort {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter no of terms");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the terms");
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The unsorted array is:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        heap(arr);

        System.out.println("The sorted array is:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    static void heapify(int a[], int n, int i) {
        int max, child;
        child = 2 * i + 1;
        max = i;
        if (child < n)
            if (a[child] > a[max])
                max = child;
        if (child + 1 < n)
            if (a[child + 1] > a[max])
                max = child + 1;
        if (max != i) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[max];
            a[max] = temp;
            heapify(a, n, max);
        }
    }

    static void buildheap(int a[]) {
        for (int i = a.length / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            heapify(a, a.length, i);
    }

    static void heap(int a[]) {
        buildheap(a);
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            int temp = a[0];
            a[0] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
            heapify(a, i, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gon, welcome to stackoverflow. what you have tried? its kind of bad asking people to do your homework..

Comment: And please: ask your instructor about the purpose of your exercise. I would teach people the exact opposite. Forcing the above code into a single method will make it unreadable. It is a truly bad idea, and I am wondering why on earth he wants you to do that...

Comment: And just for the record: don't forget about accepting an answer at some point...

Comment: The problem you are going to hit is that `heapify()` is recursive. Refactoring the code to use loops is possible, but could be tricky depending on your skill level. I strongly recommend clarifying the exact requirement of your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

You get there by simply replacing each method invocation with the actual body of the method. Of course, that will quickly lead to all kinds of confusion, given the poor naming of method parameters.

But the real challenge here (and probably your actual homework) is that you have to *rework* that `heapify()` method to **not** use recursion. In other words: you have to do the heap sort **without** using recursion. You can find some guidance [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-heap-sort/) for example.

And of course: this code is already hard to read. Forcing all code into a single method will make it unreadable and not human comprehensive. It is like the exact opposite of good practices!

Comment: On the other hand, one way to learn why good modularization matters is to be forced to deal with code that doesn't bother. (This is true for any quality deemed good about code)

Comment: Simply replacing a method call with its implementation won't work when the call is recursive.

Comment: @Jason As promised, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is replace all the code in each method to where the method is being called.

For example, instead of calling heap(arr) you can move all the code up to the place where heap(arr) is being called and continue to do so with the rest of the code.

Comment: Simply replacing a method call with its implementation won't work when the call is recursive.